# Program has stopped working. Breaking on exception: Class '_LocalLibraryMirror' has no instance getter 'classes'

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

This code does not work anymore.

```dart
String getHomePath() {
  var home = Platform.environment['HOME'];
  if(home != null) {
    return pathos.normalize(home);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

```dart
Breaking on exception: Class '_LocalLibraryMirror'
has no instance getter 'classes'.
```

Does this mean that the library "dart: mirrors" redesigned and the package "pathos" does not account for these changes?

Also, I'm surprised that package "pathos" uses "dart: mirrors" to determine in which environment it used (browser or standalone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the same problem mentioned https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/pull/408

Update to 1.1.0-dev.5.6 solved it for them.

You could check with `pub upgrade` if there is any updated package version that is not pulled due to version constraints and use `dependency_overrides` to force the newest package version.

Comment: I use package "pathos". Latest version on pub.dartlang.org 0.6.3+1, from Jul 09, 2013. Seems that it not maintained more.

Comment: pathos was replaced by path